# JavaScript: Regex to get string between ";;;"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have seen couple  similar post related my question, but I'm unable to get my Regex right.

how to get string in between ";;;" as shown below

```
;;; My Result ;;; --> My Result
;;; Title:Learning Regex ;;; --> Title:Learning Regex
;;; with all special characters !@#$%^&*()';" ;;; --> with all special characters !@#$%^&*()';"
;;; this should return nothing --> ""
```

tried below solution but no luck

```
 var str = ';;; Title:Learning Regex ;;;';
 var res= str.match(/^;{3}\w;{3}$/).pop();
```

any JavaScript Regex Guru, please help.

Comment: Well, you could at least try [`^;{3}(.*?);{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/uC1pP4/1), although it will also capture `; ssss ;;;` in `;;;; ssss ;;;;;;`.

Comment: but ... `;;;` is shorter than `;{3}`

Comment: Can you use `str.split` instead?

Comment: @mcon `str.split` vs `regex` what's the better option for multiple occurrence and by performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem with this task is that you might want to differentiate between non-three semi-colon delimiters.

I'd suggest

```
^;{3}(?!;)([\s\S]*?[^;]);{3}$
```

For standalone strings use a version with *greedy* quantifier:

```
^;{3}(?!;)([\s\S]*[^;]);{3}$
                 ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC1pP4/4)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `;{3}` - 3 semi-colons
- `(?!;)` - fail a match if the next character is a `;`
- `([\s\S]*?[^;])` - match zero or more characters (incl. a newline) up to the last 3 semi-colons, and the 4th character from the end cannot be a `;` (**NOTE**: when using with standalone strings, replace `[\s\S]*?` with `[\s\S]*`,a greedy version!)
- `;{3}` - 3 semi-colons
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Please pay attention to the **NOTE**. It is important since it impacts performance.

Comment: The explaination is really helpful. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, here's a solution using `split`.

```js
var str = ";;; My Result ;;; --> My Result;;; Title:Learning Regex ;;; --> Title:Learning Regex;;; with all special characters !@#$%^&*()';\" ;;; --> with all special characters !@#$%^&*()';\";;; this should return nothing --> \"\"";

var res = str.split(";;;");

res.forEach(function(value){
 console.log(value);
});
```

One thing to note is that there's a blank index at the beginning because it splits on the first `;;;` and you get `{'', My Result, ... }`.

Split may not help in this instance for this exact reason, but it might not be too difficult for you to use strings like `My Result ;;; --> My Result;;; Title:Learning Regex ;;; --> Title:Learning Regex;;; with all special characters !@#$%^&*()';\" ;;; --> with all special characters !@#$%^&*()';\";;; this should return nothing --> \"\"` instead. Just be careful of excess white space if you use something like this.

Also, in my opinion, a solution using `split` is better suited in this case since you know exactly what your string delimiters are. Not sure how it stands up performance wise.